# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ebooks' [first moderator election](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the two candidates:

[image: Daniel] [image: mau]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: hello all! I'll do my best

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations to both of you!

I saw [in The Appendix](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58346330#58346330) that there was some early concern about a lack of candidates. When this happens, concerns arise about the future of the site, and whether or not it will be approved to remain online in the Stack Exchange network.

It is comforting to learn that the site will continue to live, and with appointed mods available to help share the workload that Jason Down was doing single-handedly for so long.

Thanks @mau for already mentioning in the comments that you'd willing to take on this responsibility! I look forward to getting to know both of you in The Appendix over time :)

Answer (score 3):

Congrats gents! Glad to have a couple more members of the community to help with moderation.

Enjoy and shoot me any questions via the [ebooks mod chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12766/ebook-moderators) if you need assistance.

Also, just a heads up that I'll be on vacation from July 5th-9th (marked it on the dashboard) and may have no access during that week.